# Rails how to add belongs_to to gem file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rubygems, belongs-to

This is difficult for me to explain, but I need to add the `belongs_to` attribute to a model of a gem.

I am using the [`APN_on_rails`](https://github.com/timsu/apn_on_rails) gem to add push notification functionality to my web app. In this gem it creates a `model` called `Device` (`APN::Device`) which has a few fields needed for it to work.

I now need to link the `Device` model to my own `User` model. I have successfully migrated a `user_id` to the database table.

Now the only problem is adding `belongs_to` to the model. It is not in die `/app/models/` directory.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's Ruby, so you can just reopen the class and add more to it.

Create a `device.rb` file in your models directory and just add the appropriate `belongs_to` as if you created the whole model yourself. As long as you don't redefine any important methods without calling `super` it will supplement their model with just what you need. You may also need to add an `attr_accessible` or `attr_protected` to be able to use it depending on how they defined their model.

I hope that helps.